# Array sorting of key values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a poll on my website. For it I put the results into an array such as this:

```
[Answer1] => "0",
[Answer2] => "1",
[Answer3] => "0",
[Answer4] => "0"
```

The choice is the key and the number of votes is the value. Essentially when the results show I want to order by the number of votes and then also keep the same sort. So if no votes it would show in the order:

```
Answer1
Answer2
Answer3
Answer4
```

But, with "Answer2" having 1 vote it would show:

```
Answer2
Answer1
Answer3
Answer4
```

I have tried creating a custom usort function but am having no luck.
Can anybody help me with the logic how to do it please (i can do the PHP myself)?

Comment: arsort and see [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using an associative array what you are looking for is called a stable sort.
PHP's standard array sorting functions use an unstable implementation of quicksort so as you have found they will not help you here.

You could accomplish this though using `array_multisort`. By sorting by BOTH the **value** and the **key**.

With your data structure you currently have you could not do this with any of the u*sort functions BUT if you modified the data structure and added another dimension so that it looked like the following then you could:

```
array( 
  array( 
    'answer' => 1, 
    'votes' => 0, 
  ), 
  array( 
    'answer' => 2, 
    'votes' => 1, 
  ), 
)
```

So essentially the comparison function would just need to take into account both sub-indexes.

hope that helps

Comment: +1 for mentioning unstability of PHP sorting functions. Actually it should also be possible without modifying the data structure, if `array_multisort` gets a variable with the `array_keys` as second parameter.

Comment: i appreciate this help with the logic alot, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want the php function "asort":

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

it sorts the array, maintaining the index associations.

I've just noticed you're using a standard array (non-associative). if you're not fussed about preserving index associations, use sort( ):

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: It's `arsort()` (high to low)

Comment: No, asort sorts by value, which is not what the OP wanted

Comment: so if i have no votes it will appear `answeer1,answer2,answer3,answer4`. BUT if I have 1 vote on answer2 will it appear `answer2,answer1,answer3,answer4`? sorry but doesnt work

Comment: Kindly visit http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php to view all types of sorting

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I misread the question.

asort() will sort the array by value, so the highest votes will be first in the array.
thus the result will be:

```
[Answer2] => "1",
[Answer1] => "0",
[Answer3] => "0",
[Answer4] => "0"
```

or an even more complete example

```
[Answer2] => "42",
[Answer3] => "29",
[Answer1] => "18",
[Answer4] => "9"
```

---

Answer (score -1):

I think asort() will work..

```
asort($your_array);
```